# pattern of recursively splitting an array to odd and even elements

Tags: fft, recurrence, ntt

I am looking to find a pattern to recursively split an array to odd and even elements. I will try to describe the problem in the following:

suppose we have an array of length 16 as:

```
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

First iteration: splitting in odd and even

```
[0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14]
[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15]
```

which basically are

```
a[2i]   for i=0:7
a[2i+1] for i=0:7
```

splitting each of these arrays into odd and even elements again we have

```
[0,4,8,12]
[2,6,10,14]
[1,5,9,13]
[3,7,11,15]
```

that similarly are

```
4i    for i=0:3
4i+2
4i+1
4i+3
```

splitting again the array elements would be

```
[0,8]
[4,12]
.
.
[1,9]
```

or

```
8i    for i=0:1
8i+4
8i+2
8i+6
8+1
8i+5
8i+3
8i+1
```

Arrays needed to split recursively until each array has only two elements.

One things that I noticed that the bottom half is similar to the top one and we just need to add "1" to the index terms

I was wondering how Can I find the pattern for an array with an "n" elements?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your number `n` is a power of 2 (aka `2^k`):

then you will have `m` = `n/2` = `2^(k-1)` arrays with following numbers for `i` in `{0,1}`:

```
0: m*i+f(0)
1: m*i+f(1)
...
j: m*i+f(j)
...
m-1: m*i+f(m-1)
```

where `f(x)` is a function which takes an integer (`x`), transforms it into an `k-1`-bit binary number (`b`), reverses it (`rb`) and returns its decimal value (`y`).

Example for `k=4` (which looks a lot like your values):

| x | b | rb | f(x)=y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 000 | 000 | 0 |
| 1 | 001 | 100 | 4 |
| 2 | 010 | 010 | 2 |
| 3 | 011 | 110 | 6 |
| 4 | 100 | 001 | 1 |
| 5 | 101 | 101 | 5 |
| 6 | 110 | 011 | 3 |
| 7 | 111 | 111 | 7 |

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been thinking about this for days. I was actually planing to use this to design a digital hardware and I can easily flip the arrays.

Comment: @elec_hi ^^ I hope you have a fixed k, this would make everything easier ^^

Comment: Yes K is fixed and I can pad arrays with zero if it is not power of 2. I am actually going to use this for digital implementation of a bottom to top number theoretic transform calculator.